# cotegorization of a numeric variable in SAS

Tags: sas, percentile, categorization

I want to find the way to build another variable (it's ok even in the same dataset) that is the categorization of the old variable. I would choose the number of the buckets (for exemples using percentiles as cutoffs: `p10, p20, p30`, etc.).
Now I do this thing extracting the percentiles of the variable with `proc univariate`. But this give me only the percentiles (my cutoffs) and then I have to build the new variable manually using the percentiles.
How can I create this new variable giving the cutoffs and the number of buckets as input?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want equal percentage sized buckets, then `PROC RANK` might just get you want you are looking for.

```
data test;
do i=1 to 100;
 output;
end;
run;

proc rank data=test out=test2 groups=5;
var i;
ranks grp;
run;
```

That will give you 5 groups (named 0 .. 4), which should be equivalent to P20, P40, ..., P80 cutoffs.

If you wanted non-equal buckets, ie P10, P40, P60, and P90, then you would have to choose the lowest level and combine groups.  Using the groups above:

```
%let groups=10;

proc rank data=test out=test2 groups=&groups;
var var;
ranks grp;
run;

/*
    P = (grp+1)*&groups
    Cutoffs 10, 40, 60, 90
    implicit 5 new groups
*/

%let n_cutoff=4;
%let cutoffs=10, 40, 60, 90;

data test3(drop=_i cutoffs:);
set test2;
array cutoffs[&n_cutoff] (&cutoffs);

P = (grp+1)*&groups;

do _i=1 to &n_cutoff;
    if P <= cutoffs[_i] then do;
        new_grp = _i-1;
        leave;
    end;

    if _i = &n_cutoff then
        new_grp = _i;
end;

run;
```

10 is the lowest common denominator of the P values.  100/10 = 10 so we need 10 groups from `PROC RANK`.

The Data Step at the end combines the groups using the cutoffs you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Probably proc rank with groups=10 is ok. But I don't know why a lot of observation goes in a different bucket compared to the categoritization with proc univariate output.

Comment: @GiacomoRosaspina do you have a lot of ties in your data set?

Comment: @Reeza I don't know what ties are

Comment: Does variable i have duplicate values or ties in your actual data. Ties are values that are the same. In this case, your ranks may not create exactly equal groups and different proc may handle Ties differently.